# What is the difference between anger and hatred in Judaism

Tags: halacha, middos-character-traits

I see [Kitsur Shulchan aruch 29.4,13](https://web.archive.org/web/20160324113914/http://yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur29.html) Regarding anger and hatred.

What is the difference?
Is anger the expression of hatred?
Sources please.

Comment: @mevaqesh just for you כעס and  שנא

Comment: consider quoting the original text. The English words 'anger' and 'hatred' are not halakhic terms, so there is no reason to assume that they have exact meanings. | I wouldn't assume that their Hebrew counterparts have rigid specific definitions either. | Why do you assume that hatred and anger are basically synonymous? | Why mention the Kitzur in particular? Why not just ask what the respective Biblical words mean? You might even be able to pass it off as a non Hebrew question...

Comment: @mevaqesh you also have it in rambam De'ot 1.4 2.3 6.5,6,9

Comment: I know. Rambam forms the basis for that part of the Kitzur. That makes your question even more confusing to me. Is it a question about the Kitzur? About Rambam? About the definition of particular biblical words in their original context? In some later context? A question about an idea irrespective of what different words mean? Something else?

Comment: I don't not understand why you seem to understand that they are equivalent.  כעס is a loss of control as explained the Rambam you cited in deot 2, 3.  שנאה is often something without expression as the Rambam 6, 5 said about the prohibited hatred

Comment: both are bad. but are not identical

Comment: @m.r. what is the definition of each?

Comment: I recall reading in Ramba"m that, while he generally discourages anger, he does allow one to be angry at a child or student in order to discipline him to behave appropriately. This type of anger is a "false" anger, because it is done out of love. Hatred would obviously not create this type of anger. Anger, I believe is also temporary, in most cases. Hatred, OTOH, seems permanent or far more long term.

Answer (score 1):

They both arise from the same branch, namely arrogance.

in Shaarei Kedusha part 1 gate 2:

> The foundation of Fire - from it is drawn arrogance which is called
>   "Gasut HaRuach" - in being the lightest and highest of all the
>   foundations. And included in it is anger, since it is because of
>   arrogance that a man becomes angry when "his will is not being done".
>   And if he were a "shefal ruach" (lowly of spirit), and he recognized
>   his lacking, he would not at all become angry. It comes out that anger
>   and arrogance are one trait. And their derivatives are 3: kapdanus
>   (being irritable) in his heart. Because without the arrogance, he
>   would not be irritable in his heart, similar to what we explained for
>   anger. Seeking power and honor to show off to others. Hatred of others
>   because they are greater than him. And this is also a branch of
>   arrogance. (Translation my own).

Comment: +1 is this not regarding a sposific hatred (" of others because they are greater than him"), in my sources it is regarding hatred even when someone lower then you herts you

Comment: @hazoriz that is by far the most common form. you dont generally find hatred of those lower